# Android - Access TextView inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using the standard Viewpager with custom PageAdapter.

How can I access to the Viewpager's TextView, to change the font color at onPageSelected()?

## Edit 1: ViewPager Listener

```
final ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.a2viewpager);
        vp.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

            }
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                vp.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            }
            public void onPageSelected(final int currentPage) {
                ImageButton leftNav = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.a2left_nav);
                ImageButton rightNav = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.a2right_nav);
                int lastIdx = vpAadapter.getCount() - 1;


                if (receiptPool.get(currentPage).contains("_(Canceled)") == true){
                    vp.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorRed));
                }
                else {
                    vp.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorMainTextBackground));
                }


            }
        });
```

## Edit 1:  Custom Adapter

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    private Vector<View> pages;
    private activity1 act1;
    private activity2 act2;
    private Intent intent;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, Vector<View> pages) {
        super();
        this.act1 = new activity1();
        this.act2 = new activity2();
        this.mContext=context;
        this.pages=pages;
    }


    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int CurrentPage) {
        View page = pages.get(CurrentPage);

        page.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            /******/

        });

        container.addView(page);
        return page;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        // Seems to be required as a workaround.
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: could you provide the source code

Comment: @vinodh Kumar I have added some code, thx.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a custom adapter, that means that your adapter inflates all the items inside the viewPager. So check your adapter, find the xml that is inflated, and change the text color, or do it programatically in your `getView` or `instantiateItem` methods inside your adapter. But its much better if we see your code

Comment: i have add in the code for the custom adapter and the Viewpager listener.

Comment: @LouisLee i see your code, but where is the textview that you want to update? As I see this code is gibberish - or I dont understand it. What does `this.act1 = new activity1();` mean? What kind of object is that, Activity? if so please find a good tutorial and check how a viewPager adapter works - and you will get the idea

Answer (score 0):

Viewpager must be containing several fragments, first you must locate the fragment.

Below piece of code shows accessing a textview the currently displayed fragment:

```
DemoObjectFragment frag1 = (DemoObjectFragment)mViewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(mViewPager, mViewPager.getCurrentItem());

frag1.textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I have added code to my post, please explain how to apply yours to my case